# Unable to mount network drive Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, fstab, nas

I have a network drive via a Qnap TS-412.
I've been trying to get this drive to automount to my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

The drive can be mounted by going to the file manager, clicking "connect to server" and clicking on the "smb://172.26.***.200/home" link and pressing connect. However when I put all of this information into the fstab I have errors thrown at me.
The current error is as follows:

`mount: special device //172.26.***.200 does not exist`

The current command I am using is as follows:

```
//172.26.***.200/home/backup       /media/network-backup   ext4    credentials=/home/john/.smbcredentials 0       0
```

I did come across a post which recommended using sec=ntlm, which I have tried without success, as well as trying ideas for countless other articles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have ext4 change it to cifs type.

Comment: I have already tried this, I then get a "mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //172.26.***.200" message.

Comment: Try to mount until `/home`..

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have ext4 in your fstab option, change this to `cifs`.eg:

`//host/samba /mnt/samba cifs ....`